# How to keep <li> elements on single line in fixed width <ul>?

Tags: css, html-lists, fixed-width

I've a header `div` and a menu `ul` below it. I'd like to accomplish 2 things:

1) the `ul` should have the same width as the `div` (outer vertical borders exactly same x position
2) I'd like to keep the spacing between `li` elements roughly equal

With some trial and error on the `li`'s margins and padding I roughly achieved the first point in Google Chrome (please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ANj)) but in Firefox the `li`'s don't fit in the `ul` so they don't stay on a single line. Also, the last `li` tends to 'spill over' to a second line when zooming in/out.

I tried it with `margin:5px auto` and `padding:5px auto` on the `li` elements but here `auto` seems to mean zero.

Is this really difficult/impossible or am I overlooking something obvious?

I also tried `width:fit-contents` but that didn't help either.

Comment: remove letter-spacing from ul#mmenu li

Comment: I don't see any difference between FF & CR in your fiddle.. can you post a screenshot explaining the desire behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I edited a whole lot in your CSS, check the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/y4ANj/8/).

Basicly, this is what I've done:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 960px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

The ul is displayed as a table, with the li's as table-cells, making it as width as the header. Within the li i display the anchors as a block, making them fill the whole li. Hope it suits you.

P.s. make sure you remove the class `cf` from the `ul` when you use this.

Comment: This work fine, although i generally say to people although this is perfectly workable solution, unless your dealing with tabular data, why not use other options

Comment: Well, it makes the elements *act* like an table, not being a table. I don't mind using it like this. It bothers me more when people try to use list or divs to display tabular data. (offtopic)

Answer (score 9):

I think some fellow frustrates may find this useful:

```
.main-menu ul li ul li{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
ul#mmenu li
{
padding:7px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ANj/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust the padding in `ul#mmenu` I changed the padding to `padding:7px 23px;` and it stays in a single line,but there will be a blank space at the right end of the last menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can give absolute position to li items and position them (first have left:0, second: left:100px or so... last have right:0 and so on). That way they will always be at the same place when you zoom.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to avoid CSS `table` and `table-cell`, which by the way, I have no probelm with you can use `text-align:justify` on the `UL` with a couple of tweaks.

Basic HTML:

```
<ul id='mmenu'>
   <li><a href='#'>Blah Blah Blah Blah</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Blah Blah</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Blah Blah Blah Blah</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Blah Blah</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note we've lost the clearfix because: a) We're not going to use floats and b)it breaks this solution.

CSS:

```
ul#mmenu{
   width:100%;
   margin:15px 0 10px 0;
   overflow:hidden;
   text-align:justify; /*Added this*/
}

ul#mmenu li{
   letter-spacing:.05em;
   color:#0a93cd;
   /*Now inline blocks instead of blocks floated left*/
   display:inline-block; 
   font:24px arial;
   padding:7px 26px;
   background:#fff;
   border-left:2px solid #0a93cd;
   border:2px solid #0a93cd;
   border-radius:13px;
   text-align:center;
}

/*Now for the hacky part....
  ...justify does not, by design, justify the last row of text
  therfore we need to add an additional, invisible line*/
ul#mmenu:after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I have also removed the `:first-child` style in the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ANj/41/)

Comment: I need to show more li in single line and if the width in low then it will hide the content with over flow hidden http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/y4ANj/59/